# Bra-Ket and inner products

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, definition

We denote a scalar product of two vectors $a, b$ in Hilbert space $H$ as $(a,b)$ or $\langle a, b\rangle$.

In Bra-Ket notation, we denote a vector $a$ in Hilbert space as $|a\rangle$. Also, we say that bras such as $\langle b|$ belong to the dual space $H^*$ . So Bras are linear transformations that map kets to a number.

Then it isn't always true that $\langle a \mid b\rangle=(a,b)$.

In quantum mechanics the above equality holds, is it that we define bra in such a way so that the above equality holds? Are there cases when the above equation is not true?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you ask. $\forall T \in \mathcal{H}^{*}, !\exists \, x_{T} \, / \, T(y) = \left\langle x_{T}, y \right\rangle \, \forall y \in \mathcal{H}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem

Comment: I'm sorry i am not able to put it clearly. I'm saying is <a| |b> = (a, b) always? How is that so.

Comment: It is so, it is just notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just notation!
$$\langle \psi|\chi\rangle \equiv (\langle \psi|,|\chi\rangle )$$
Dirac denoted the number resulting from the pairing of the covector $\langle \psi|$ with the vector $|\chi\rangle $ by the "bra-c-ket" symbol $\langle \psi|\chi\rangle $.

---

Furthermore, We can regard the dagger map as either determining the inner-product on $V$ via
$$\langle |\psi\rangle ,|\chi\rangle \rangle \equiv (|\psi\rangle ^\dagger,|\chi\rangle )=(\langle \psi|,|\chi\rangle )\equiv \langle \psi|\chi\rangle  $$
or being determined by it as
$$|\psi\rangle ^\dagger\equiv \langle |\psi\rangle,\ \ \rangle \equiv \langle \psi|$$